# Clone and update all repositories from user without authentication at bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull, git-clone

I have to many repos, and some times i need to create more, but right now i am using one script with `git pull` that updates all the actual repos that i have at mid night, and when i need to add a new repo i do `git clone` for that specific repo through URL, manually, but sometimes i forget to do this because it is annoying.

After search about it, i have found ways to do this like i have did with `git pull` with several repos but i have not found anything for people that usually add more repos.

So is there a way where i could `git clone` all my user repos (or from a team) and then `git pull` all my repos at once?

Comment: Do the URL addresses stay the same for the repos you are cloning?

Comment: Stays the same but in the end it adds the name of the repository, git repo is the exact repo name, for example: https://<username>:<password>@bitbucket.org/<usarname>/<git repo>

Comment: Can I assume that you don't know the repo names in advance?  If you don't, you will need some input to capture the repo name and append it to the URL.

Comment: I know the names but i dont want to input every time i add a new one. I have found that through an api for bitbucket.org i am able to list repos but i think that they should be public to apear there, dont know. You can check that here: https://haroldsoh.com/2011/10/07/clone-all-repos-from-a-bitbucket-source/

Comment: Do you need to grab repos that are not public?

Comment: yes all my repos are private =/

Answer (score 0):

Use the REST API to get a list of all your repositories like for user `tutorial` https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/tutorial, then loop over the list and clone / pull all of them automatically.

If you need to see private repos, you have to authenticate your request like described on https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication. If you did not enable 2-factor-authentication for your account you can simply use Basic Auth, otherwise you have to authenticate using OAuth.

Comment: with 2-factor-authentication through SSH i will be able to list all my private repos? or i will have to auth per repo like i was doing with Basic Auth?

Comment: If you have enabled 2-factor-authentication for your account, you cannot use Basic Auth, but have to use OAuth for authentication to the REST API. Follow the link and be enlightened. ;-)